# DRF: OneToOne relation with unique_together

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am trying to understand how to use a OnetoOne relation with unique_together. Currently trying to make use of them in my serializer and view with no success.

Models:

```
class Employees(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    position = models.CharField()
    phone = models.IntegerField()


class WorkSchedule(models.Model):
    employee = models.OneToOneField('Employees')
    workday = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('employee', 'workday'),)
```

First question:
Since the relation is OneToOne if i didn't have unique_together then each employee could appear in WorkSchedule once. However since i have unique_together this is not the case anymore. Correct?

Second Question:
How would i use such models to return all employees and their workschedules like this

```
{
    "employees": [
        {
            "employee": "John",
            "workschedule": [
                {
                    workday: "2022-03-03"
                },
                {
                    workday: "2022-03-04"
                }
        },
        {
        
            "employee": "Tom",
            "workschedule": [
                {
                    workday: "2022-03-03"
                },
                {
                    workday: "2022-03-04"
                }
        }
}
```

I was able to do this with using a ForeignKey(no unique_together) and a Nested Serializer however i wasn't able to do it with using the two models as they are above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First question: Since the relation is OneToOne if i didn't have `unique_together` then each employee could appear in WorkSchedule once. However since i have unique_together this is not the case anymore. Correct?

**No**: a `OneToOneField` is a `ForeignKey` with a uniqness constraint. The fact that you later define an extra constraint does not matter. This thus means that your `unique_together` has no impact: since the `OneToOneField` already guarantees that the `employee` is unique, this implies that the combination with the `workday` will be unique, even without specifying a `unique_together`.

You thus should thus use a `ForeignKey`, so:

```
class WorkSchedule(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employees', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    workday = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['employee', 'workday'], name='unique_employee_workday')
        ]
```

> Second Question: How would i use such models to return all employees and their workschedules like this.

By using a `ForeignKey`. It make no sense here to use a `OneToOneField`: this only makes sense if each `WorkSchedule` has exactly one `Employee`, and each `Employee` has *at most* one `WorkSchedule`.

---

> **Note**: As the [documentation on **`unique_together`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) says, the `unique_together` constraint will likely become deprecated. The documentation advises to use the [**`UniqueConstraint`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) from Django's [*constraint
> framework*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint).

Answer (score 1):

Trying to understand unique together -

Code example -

```
class WorkSchedule(models.Model):
    employee = models.CharField()
    workday = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('employee', 'workday'),)
```

Unique together here means every object of WorkSchedule will be unique when you compare considering two fields at a time.

Eg.- suppose first object is

```
{
    "employee" : "A"
    "workday" : "A"
}
```

Now no other object can have values **employee** = **A** and **workday** = **A** combined.

So other objects can have values such as (2 cases) -

> 1. If **employee** value is **A** in any other object, **workday** must **not be A**. Otherwise, it will fail at unique together constrain.
> 2. Same, if the **workday** value is **A** in any other object, the **employee can not be A**, Otherwise, it will again fail at unique together constrain.

Coming back to your question -

since you have used **OneToOneField** for **employee** in **WorkSchedule**, so by default there will be no two same values of employee and you can neglect using unique_together.

But again the result which you are expecting, will create two objects of WorkSchedule (from the result example) with the **same employee** and **different workday**. So you can not use OneToOneField, you will have to use **ForeignKey** for employee and make sure employee and workday are unique together.

It is also mentioned in the documentation that unique_together will be depreciated in the future, so you will have to code as mentioned by sir @Willem Van Onsem.